# Troubleshooting frozen php scripts

Tags: php, process, execution

I'm troubleshooting multiple **huge** php scripts. One of those scripts usually hangs for a very long time. Is their a way through which I can find out the line number by which the script hanged ?

Note that every single script is executed multiple times simultaneously, so I have numerous instances running.

The script is very big and this happens randomly so it's very exhausting to write debugging lines all over the script. If I do so the logs will eat up my disks pace so please, I need a solution that has nothing to do with logging.

Can some kind of a process explorer do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install the [xdebug extension](http://xdebug.org/) and use [profiling](http://xdebug.org/docs/profiler). Then view the profiler output files in [WinCacheGrind](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wincachegrind/) (Windows) or [KCacheGrind](http://kcachegrind.sourceforge.net/html/Home.html) (Linux)

Comment: @MuhammadGelbana Yes it will. You should disable profiling for production.

Comment: It's a production server already. Is there a way to do that without running the scripts in debug mode ? Can I specify debugging mode for a specific script ?

Comment: yes you can enable profiling just for a certain script or a certain section of code. Check the xdebug documentation about the available php functions